# Erasing multiline #define macros with php regexp (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex, macros, preg-replace

I am trying to erase multiline macros in C file with PHP regexp

This one of the examples

```
this one should stay
#define HI    something is here ()d5gf           \
dgkdflgj \
it ends here
this one should stay
        #define HII something is here 2
this one should stay
```

Output should look like this:

```
this one should stay
this one should stay
this one should stay
```

I am using this regexp, but it doesn't work properly:

```
preg_replace("/#define[^\n\\]+(\\\n[^\n\\])*/u", "", $input_lines);
```

Note: the file is in UTF-8, thats why the u in preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~#define(?=\s)(?>.*\\\\\R)*.*\R?~u';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $code);
```